# Getting AD's _id_token_claims in django middleware

Tags: python, django, azure, active-directory

```
from django.conf import settings
from ms_identity_web import IdentityWebPython
identity_web = IdentityWebPython(request)
print(identity_web)
claims = identity_web._id_token_claims
```

How do I get the details from identity_web like when I get them using `claims = request.identity_context_data._id_token_claims` in my view functions ?

`claims = identity_web._id_token_claims` is throwing `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'identity_context_data'`

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this problem and the same issue.
I'm [following this pattern here](https://github.com/BillmanH/msdocs-python-django-webapp-quickstart/blob/main/hello_azure/views.py).

```py
@ms_identity_web.login_required
def my_view(request):
    context = {}
    context["username"] = request.identity_context_data.username
    context["oid"] = request.identity_context_data._id_token_claims['oid']
    return render(request, "app/my_view.html", context)
```

Note that:

- The `identity_context_data` is in the request.
- `request.identity_context_data._id_token_claims` is a dict of values that has everything you are looking for.
- **Note** that you probably don't want to pipe all of those values into your view. Some of that is sensitive stuff and could cause security issues if piped directly into your view.